# How to remove the border in react- bootsrap accordion on the text

Tags: react-bootstrap

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6OM9.png)

```
<Accordion>
          <Accordion.Item eventKey="0">
            <Card style={{ margin: 10 }}>
              <Card.Header style={{ display: "flex" }}>
                <span
                  style={{
                    flex: 1,
                    fontSize: 18,
                    color: "black",
                    textDecoration: "none",
                    cursor: "pointer",
                    alignSelf: "center",
                  }}
                >
                  <Accordion.Header >{note.title}</Accordion.Header>
                </span>
```

The border on the text came when I applied accordion before it was not there

Comment: Did you try adding inline style `border: none` property on the specific element ? Also refer this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this CSS, and it works:

```css
.accordion .card-header button {
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this  works I tried adding inline css and it did not work

Comment: inline css is not best practice. why don't use external css?
in react-bootsrap you dont have access all component's childs style inline.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the following CSS rule:

```css
.accordion-header {
    border: none;
}
```